# Authentication to your bot via Azure Bot Service

Tags: bots, azure-ad-graph-api

Unable to authorize multiple users for a BOT within the same organization using Azure AD authentication

Following are the steps we tried.
1. Created an office 365 organization, so as to be the admin of the Azure AD

2. Registered the Azure AD app thru app registrations on Azure in the same Org, and then assigned the permissions to the app to read emails and calendar, by following the URL - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp%2Cbot-msgraph-auth
3. Then created the web app bot under azure
4. Then under [OAuth Connection Settings] settings of the bot added the Azure AD app details, first added as Azure AD V1.0 with as per the recommendation in the URL of Microsoft
5. Used the standard template code of the project - BotAuthenticaionMSGraph from the Github sample code repository -  https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore
6. In the sample code, we just need to edit the appsettings.json file to add the [ConnectionName, MicrosoftAppId, MicrosoftAppPassword]
7. Then published the local bot code to the app service of the web app bot on Azure
8. Tested the Bot Auth on the [Test in Web Chat] on Azure -- It works for my Azure AD
9. Then enabled the Directline Channel for bot and distributed bot to other users of the same organization
10. The issue is here - when the other user opens the bot, they can see the emails and calendar of the admin user who has already logged in initially. So when the other user logs off and logs in thru his AD credential, then only his emails and calendar data is available since then.

Issue - So, at a given point of time only one user's o365 data is visible globally on the bot chat, and not individual user's data who logs in for that session. The AD token is not per user session but instead its a universal token across for all the conversations.

When I use the Azure AD V2, I get the bad request while trying to login.

Please help. Thanks.

https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore

used the BotAuthenticaionMSGraph project

Expected is, every user should be able to log in individually, and only his data shud be visible on the bot conversation distinctively.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the sample code and it works fine for both Azure AD V1 and V2.

I followed [Azure AD v2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp%2Cbot-msgraph-auth#azure-ad-v2) to configure it. Don't forget to enter `Mail.Read Mail.Send openid profile User.Read User.ReadBasic.All` for **Scopes**. It's different from Azure AD V1. Otherwise, it will return 400 bad request while trying to login.

I didn't reproduce the first issue. Could you tell where the other user opens the bot? From "Test in Web Chat"?

---

**Update**

You need to be aware that your are dealing with two user identities:

- The user’s identity in a channel.
- The user’s identity in an identity provider that the bot is
  interested in.

See [Security considerations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#security-considerations). When a bot asks user A in a channel to sign-in to an identity provider P, the sign-in process must assure that user A is the one that signs into P. If another user B is allowed to sign-in, then user A would have access to user B’s resource through the bot.

To enable the protection, you need to configure trusted Origins and tamper-proof user IDs.

You can refer to the [sample code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#code-examples).

And this blog [Using WebChat with Azure Bot Service’s Authentication](https://blog.botframework.com/2018/09/01/using-webchat-with-azure-bot-services-authentication/) provides more detailed infomration.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the response Allen. Yes, I had also added the Scopes for AD V2, nevertheless will give a shot again and see how that goes... Next to answer your question, for the other users following is how I am making the bot available.

Comment: 1. Once I add the Auth settings in the Bot, 
2. Then I enable the Directline Channel for that bot, cos for somereason the webchat is not working. 
3. Then Publish the bot on a custom website using the following script on that website, following is the script tag where i use the directline secret and the botname. (Seperate Comment below)

Comment: <script>
        var model = {
            "userId": "You",
            "userName": "You",
            "botId": "Alfred",
            "botIconUrl": "//bot-framework.azureedge.net/bot-icons-v1/bot-framework-default.png",
            "botName": "MyBotName",
            "secret": "*************************************************************",
            "iconUrl": "//bot-framework.azureedge.net/bot-icons-v1/bot-framework-default.png",
            "directLineUrl": "https://webchat.botframework.com/v3/directline",

Comment: "webSocketEnabled": "true",
            "speechTokenEndpoint": "https://api.botframework.com/v3/speechtoken",
            "speechEnabled": false,
            "cssUrl": "/css/botchat.css",
            "cssFullWindowUrl": "/css/botchat-fullwindow.css",
            "botChatJavaScriptUrl": "/scripts/botchat.js",
        };
</script>